# how to set charging to 80% on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, asus, battery

I have a Asus ROG GL503 with Ubuntu 20.04 I want to limit my charging to 80%, apparently according to the latest kernel it is now possible but it seems to me that the BATTERY_CHARGE_THRESHOLD file is missing in the kernel. How can I limit my charging to 80%
I have attached a photo of the terminal showing all the files and kernel version.

[image]

Comment: Why limit yourself to only 80% of the time you can use your system?  And no... it will not have your battery last longer. Li-Ioncells don't like heat, deep charges and are limited to about 5 years anyways. So keep vents clean, don't discharge it to 0 and get a new one when it starts to die.

Comment: well theres a functions from asus in windows where it allows you to limit battery charging thresholf to 60 and 80% so I want that in Ubuntu as well

Comment: Well if the hardware is not supported on Linux you are not going to get this working w.o the help from ASUS. Can you try this: `sudo apt install tlp acpi-call-dkms
 && sudo tlp setcharge 60 80`  and see if that works? The 60 is the start and 80 the stop threshold.

Comment: 'Error: battery charge thresholds not available.'

Comment: As of https://github.com/tshakalekholoane/bat?tab=readme-ov-file#requirements, this feature needs a 5.4 kernel but Ubuntu 18 has a 4.15 kernel by default. But a 5.4 kernel can be installed from the official Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [command line application](https://github.com/tshakalekholoane/bat) that does this.

The easiest way to get started is download the app from the [releases page](https://github.com/tshakalekholoane/bat/releases/) and run

```
$ ./bat --help
```

from the terminal in the directory where it is located which should show the help documentation.

If there's an error, it might have to do with permissions. The following command might solve the problem.

```
chmod +x ./bat
```

Basically, running

```
$ ./bat --threshold
```

will print out the current threshold.

To set a new threshold, say 60%, run

```
./bat --threshold 60
```

To persist the current threshold between restarts, run

```
sudo ./bat --persist
```

Note: Persisting uses [systemd](https://systemd.io/) under the hood but this is bundled with most Linux distributions including Ubuntu.

Tip: Putting the app in a directory like `/usr/local/bin/` that is in the `$PATH` will enable you to run it from anywhere and not just in the directory the app is in. Then the above commands become,

```
bat --help
```

```
bat --threshold 60
```

```
bat --persist
```

respectively.

Comment: From https://github.com/tshakalekholoane/bat#disclaimer: Bat works for some ASUS and Lenovo ThinkPad laptops only. I can confirm that: Does not work on HP ZBook G6 with Kernel 6.1 (no /sys/class/power_supply/*/*threshold file) despite the availability of an BIOS option to limit the battery charge level to 80 %.